# Google drive usage statistics difference between google drive UI and API

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

We are using google drive API's [About.Get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) method to return an [Abount resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource).

In google drive statistics displayed as below.

[image]

But if we are use About resource of google drive response will be getting as follow.

```
{
"quotaBytesTotal": "16106127360",
"quotaBytesUsed": "17108627",
"quotaBytesUsedAggregate": "136771970",
"quotaBytesUsedInTrash": "0",
"quotaBytesByService": [
    {
        "serviceName": "DRIVE",
        "bytesUsed": "22255358"
    },
    {
        "serviceName": "GMAIL",
        "bytesUsed": "119663343"
    },
    {
        "serviceName": "PHOTOS",
        "bytesUsed": "0"
    }
}
```

Reference link for drive API's [about resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get).

Comment: What part of that do you think is different?

Comment: If we convert bytes to Megabyte then difference can be found in total quota, usage and quota by services all three are different.

Comment: Are you counting a megabyte as 1 million bytes?  If you instead count it as 2^20 bytes (which is common), I think the numbers check out.

Comment: I am counting a megabyte as a  2^20 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.whatsabyte.com/P1/byteconverter.htm

22255358 = 21.22 Mb

119663343 = 114.11986 Mb

Where is the issue ?

1Mb = 2^10 kb
1kb = 2^10 b(ytes)

EDIT:
you are right, they should/may have used **Mib**

> 1000 bytes
>
> In the International System of Units (SI) the prefix kilo- means 1000
>   (103); therefore one kilobyte is 1000 bytes in this system. The unit
>   symbol is kB.
>
> This is the definition recommended by the International
>   Electrotechnical Commission (IEC).[1] This definition, and related
>   definitions of prefixes mega- = 1000000, giga- = 1000000000, etc., are
>   used for data transfer rates[2] in computer networks, internal bus,
>   hard drive and flash media transfer speeds, and for the capacities of
>   most storage media, particularly hard drives,[3] flash-based
>   storage,[4] and DVDs. It is also consistent with the other uses of the
>   SI prefixes in computing, such as CPU clock speeds or measures of
>   performance.
>
> The Mac OS X 10.6 file manager is a notable example of this usage in
>   software. Since Snow Leopard, file sizes are reported with decimal
>   prefixes.[5] 1024 bytes
>
> In some fields of information technology, the kilobyte instead refers
>   to 1024 (210) bytes.[6][7][8] This usage originated as compromise
>   jargon for multiples that needed to be expressed in powers of 2, but
>   lacked a convenient unit prefix. As 1024 (210) approximates 1000
>   (103), the corresponding SI prefixes were used for the multiples that
>   represent powers of 1024.
>
> This definition, and related definitions of mega = 1048576 (=10242),
>   etc., are almost invariably used for random-access memory capacities,
>   such as main memory and CPU cache sizes, due to the binary addressing
>   of memory.[a] These "binary meanings" of kilobyte, megabyte, etc., are
>   also used by some computer operating systems when reporting disk
>   capacities and file sizes.[9][unreliable source?]
>
> The binary representation of 1024 bytes typically uses the symbol KB
>   (uppercase K). The B is often omitted in informal use. For example, a
>   processor with 65,536 bytes of cache might be said to have "64K" of
>   cache. kibibyte Main article: Kibibyte
>
> In December 1998, the IEC addressed such multiple usages and
>   definitions by creating prefixes such as kibi, mebi, gibi, etc., to
>   unambiguously denote powers of 1024.[10] Thus the kibibyte, symbol
>   KiB, represents 210 = 1024 bytes. These prefixes are now part of the
>   International System of Quantities. The IEC further specified that the
>   kilobyte should only be used to refer to 1000 bytes. However, the
>   kilobyte is still commonly used to refer to 1024 bytes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte