# DriveApp.getStorageUsed() and summing the file sizes returned by DriveApp.getFiles() do not match.

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

=================== Problem

When I use the following code :

```
Logger.log(DriveApp.getStorageUsed())
```

I get the value : 6.888066988E9

The number matches the number displayed on GDrive. The issue arises when I use this code :

```
var files = DriveApp.getFiles()
var fileSizeTotal = 0;

while (files.hasNext()) {
  fileSizeTotal += files.next().getSize()
}
```

I get the value : 3.539154182E9

The numbers should be the same by my logic, but clearly are not...

=================== Question

What is causing the discrepancy, and how can I make the summation of file sizes in the iteration match that of the DriveApp.getStorageUsed() call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your question, at first, I thought that this difference is related to the trash box. So I made a sample script to verify this.

As a sample file, **I put 2 text files with the size of 100 kbytes on cleaned Google Drive. And I put one file in the trash box.** Because Google Docs has no file size, as you know.

### Sample Script :

In order to use this sample, please enable Drive API at [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) and Google API console. And please execute `run()`.

```
function run(){
  var res;
  res = getTotalFilesize(true)
  Logger.log(res)
  res = getTotalFilesize(false)
  Logger.log(res)
}

function getTotalFilesize(trash) {
  var token = "dummy";
  var filesize　=　0;
  var numberOfFilesWithSize　=　0;
  var numberOfFiles　=　0;
  while (token) {
    var res = Drive.Files.list({
      q: trash ? "" : "trashed=false",
      maxResults: 1000,
      fields: "items(id, fileSize), nextPageToken",
      pageToken: token && token != "dummy" ? token : ""
    });
    token = res.nextPageToken;
    numberOfFiles += res.items.length;
    res.items.forEach (function(e) {
      if (e.fileSize) {
        numberOfFilesWithSize++;
        filesize += parseInt(e.fileSize, 10);
      }
    });
  }
  return {
    IncludeTrash: trash ? "yes" : "no",
    TotalFilesize: filesize,
    NumberOfFilesWithSize: numberOfFilesWithSize,
    TotalFiles: numberOfFiles
  };
}
```

### Result :

```
{NumberOfFilesWithSize=2.0, TotalFiles=2.0, TotalFilesize=200000.0, IncludeTrash=yes}
{NumberOfFilesWithSize=1.0, TotalFiles=1.0, TotalFilesize=100000.0, IncludeTrash=no}
```

The results of `getStorageUsed()` and `getSize()` are 200000.0 and 100000.0, respectively. And shared files are included as outside of the trash box. So when a file with the size of 100 kBytes is shared, both above results is added 100 kBytes.

### Discussion :

From these results, I think that the difference between `getStorageUsed()` and `getSize()` is whether the files are included in the trash box.

But I think that there may be also other factors. If you use this sample, can I ask you about your result? If your result is not the same to my estimation, we can know the existence of other factors.

If this information will be helpful for you, I'm glad.

### Added :

Also you can retrieve the storage information using `Drive.About.get()`. Thank you @Sagar Kanabar.

```
var obj = Drive.About.get();
var out = {
  usageInDrive: obj.quotaBytesUsed,
  usageInTrash: obj.quotaBytesUsedInTrash
};
Logger.log(out)

>>> {usageInTrash=100000, usageInDrive=200000}
```

From this, it can be known 100kb in Drive and 100kb in Trash.

Comment: pls check this SO questions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150707/google-drive-usage-statistics-difference-between-google-drive-ui-and-api

Comment: @Sagar Kanabar I have forgot ``Drive.About.get()``. Thank you for your information.

Comment: @Jack Dalton I'm glad it could be useful for you.